# Grouping using analytic functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below. Group by id and If count(item) >1 and if there are duplicate items, take distinct first and then apply following condition.
1) If count(item) > 1 then, filter the data which is equal to 65 or 66. 
2) If count(item) = 1, do nothing.

```
+----+------+
| Id | Item |
+----+------+
|  1 |  65  |
+----+------+
|  1 |  66  |
+----+------+
|  1 |  01  |
+----+------+
|  2 |  93  |
+----+------+
|  3 |  11  |
+----+------+
|  3 |  12  |
+----+------+
|  4 |  23  |
+----+------+
|  4 |  23  |
+----+------+
```

Output:

```
+----+------+
| Id | Item |
+----+------+
|  1 |  65  |
+----+------+
|  1 |  66  |
+----+------+
|  2 |  93  |
+----+------+
|  4 |  23  |
+----+------+
```

So far tried this.

```
select id, item
from (select table.*, count(1) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from table
     ) tablt
where cnt > 1 and item in (65, 66) or cnt = 1;
```

Comment: Can you show your predicates in pseudo code form with indentation that lets us see where the AND and OR operators should be?

Comment: One additional question, which you can answer by editing your post again: are (4,23) and (4,23) rows in the table and is (4.23) an output row? It looks so but editing the question will make it unambiguous.

Comment: Why would one use `COUNT(1)` instead of `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @DavidFaber Good question. The answer is COUNT(1) is *marginally* faster than COUNT(*). At least it is in 12.1.0.2 (still after all these years). Just try a million iterations of a 1000 column table with one row. If you want to ask the question, I'll post my benchmark.

Comment: According to Tom Kyte, `COUNT(1)` is just rewritten internally as `COUNT(*)` and before that was the case (Oracle 7.x), `COUNT(*)` was the faster of the two.

Answer (score 0):

I think I interpreted your predicates correctly:

```
select distinct id, item
from (select x.*,
            count(1) over (partition by id) as cnt,
            count(distinct item) over (partition by id) as cntdist
      from x 
     ) tablt
where cnt > 1 and item in (65, 66) or cntdist = 1;
```

But it really depends on what you mean when you use the verb "filter" and when you use the imperative "do nothing".

When I see the verb "filter", I interpret it to mean "filter out". But based upon your output data, it looks like you mean "filter out everything but 65 and 66".

When you wrote "do nothing", I could easily interpret that to mean "do not show a row". But based upon the output, it looks like you mean "do nothing to prevent the row from showing in the output". The only problem I see with the latter rule is that you are showing (4,23) only once. I have implemented that feature but only by interpreting the latter rule based upon the output you show.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using following code:

```
with t1 as 
(select id, item, count(1) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from tablet
     ) 
select id, item
from t1
where 
    cnt > 1 
and 
    item in (65, 66)
or 
    cnt = 1
;
```

Requirement were not very clear to me, but I am sure "with" clause will resolve your purpose.

- Abhi

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this condition "cnt > 1 and item in (65, 66)" in ()  like below

```
select id, item
from (select table.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
  from table
 ) tablt
where (cnt > 1 and item in (65, 66)) or cnt = 1;
```